# Get checkbox name, value and checked state in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following 4 checkboxes, generated dynamically. In the angular component, I would like to retrieve the "name", "value" and "state" of the checkbox.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="automotive" 
       value="car" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults(obj, $event)">

<input type="checkbox" 
       name="automotive" 
       value="truck" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults(obj, $event)">

<input type="checkbox" 
       name="apparel" 
       value="shirts" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults(obj, $event)">

<input type="checkbox" 
       name="apparel" 
       value="pants" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults(obj, $event)">
```

**Component:**

```
filterResults(obj: any, isChecked: boolean){
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(isChecked); // {}, true || false
}
```

I am able to get the state of the checkbox, but not the name and value. Upon printing to the console, `obj` is undefined. I would like to apply filters to a dataset based on the name and value of the checkbox.

How do I get the name and value of the checked checkboxes, so I can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may replace your `ngModelChange` event to `click` event where you pass the `event` object as

```
(change)="GetStats($event)"
```

and in the component method, try to get name, value and checked state as

```
GetStats(event: Event) {
    console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value, event.target.checked);
}
```

See more in the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-dynamic-checkbox-attributes

Answer (score 1):

You could add a dynamic id to each checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" [attr.id]="uniqueIdHere" ... >
```

Then access your checkbox properties like so:

```
var checkboxValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("uniqueIdHere")).value;
```

If your checkboxes are generated via a loop, you could use the index as part of the `[attr.id]`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to know what version you are working on.
This would be one of the approaches:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
   name="automotive" 
   value="car" (change)="checkValues($event)" 
   ngModel 
   (ngModelChange)="filterResults(obj, $event)">
```

and in the respective .ts file

```
checkValues(e: any) { console.log(e) }
```

You must find all the attributes you are looking for in the **source** property.

Comment: Angular 7 is the version I am using.

Comment: Perfect, the above method should work and fetch all the values you were expecting. Also I personally prefer Angular Material https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can makes this:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="automotive" 
       value="car" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults({name: 'automotive', value: 'car'}, $event)">

<input type="checkbox" 
       name="automotive" 
       value="truck" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults({name: 'automotive', value: 'truck'}, $event)">

<input type="checkbox" 
       name="apparel" 
       value="shirts" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults({name: 'apparel', value: 'shirts'}, $event)">

<input type="checkbox" 
       name="apparel" 
       value="pants" 
       ngModel 
       (ngModelChange)="filterResults({name: 'apparel', value: 'pants'}, $event)">
```